# Street-level parking in French

Tags: vocabulaire, transports

I am trying to translate “street level parking” into French.

In English it is an expression. It describes parking on a street level.

My attempts: “stationnement au niveau de la rue”, “stationnement sur la chaussée”.

Comment: Although I don’t think there’s a noun associated with it, street-level parking often requires knowing how to parallel park along the curb/curbside and it might be interesting to note that in French the verb for this is “{se} garer en créneau” or “faire un créneau” (or even “{se} garer le long des trottoirs”, but I’ve often seen [and experienced] this result in **at least** 2 tires being squarely **on** the sidewalks, putting them in fact 6 inches or so **above** street-level and therefore technically not **at** or **on** it!)

Answer (score 6):

On parle souvent de *stationnement de surface* ou *stationnement sur voirie* pour distinguer de parking (sous-entendu *souterrain*).

Answer (score 3):

"On street parking" would be "stationnement sur rue".

<strike>If you mean a parking spot inside a building that's on street level, I'd use "parking au rez-de-chaussée".</strike>

Edit: "stationnement sur la chaussée" works too!

Answer (score 1):

- stationnement de surface ou en surface
- stationnement au niveau de la rue
- stationnement extérieur (mais peut être en hauteur, sur un immeuble)
- stationnement de rue , s'il est réellement **sur** la rue
- stationnement sur la chaussée , équivalent au précédent
- stationnement de voirie ou sur voirie , équivalent aux deux précédents, plus stylé

Answer (score 0):

How about:

> des emplacements de stationnement au rez de chaussée

Comment: rez-de-chaussée concerne les étages des immeubles.

Answer (score -1):

There is no special expression for that.
You might simply say "parking au rez-de-chaussée"
or "aire de stationnement au rez-de-chaussée".